# Expression Engine limiting pagination and reverse related entries

Tags: expressionengine

I have an EE site running EE 1.7. It is a magazine site that has monthly "Editions", each edition may or may not have a book review in it. On the site, I need to list the book reviews, in reverse chronological order by edition. Here's my code:

```
{exp:weblog:entries weblog="editions" orderby="edition-date" sort="desc" disable="categories|member_data|trackbacks" limit="10" paginate="bottom"}
 {reverse_related_entries weblog="book-reviews"}
  ....
```

My problem is that the pagination is working based on the editions weblog, thus paging through editions that do NOT contain any book reviews. Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried using the search parameter to limit the editions to those where there is a related entry? http://expressionengine.com/legacy_docs/modules/weblog/parameters.html#par_search

Comment: The `search` parameter would work if she was showing Related Entries, but it won't work for Reverse Related Entries.

Comment: Do the entry dates of the `book-reviews` entries not correspond roughly to the "edition-date" field of the `editions` entries? Do they need to be *grouped* by edition?

Comment: Sadly, the entry dates of the book reviews are not meaningful, as much of this site was post-populated back to 2005 or so (in 2010). They do need to be grouped by edition, yes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little tricky, you'll need to use an embed for this (or alternately you could create a small plugin to do this in a similar fashion).

Try this setup in your template. Replace the weblog_ids in the query with your own (in this example, **1** is **editions** and **2** is **book-reviews**).

```
{embed="embeds/reviews" entry_ids="{exp:query 
    sql="SELECT DISTINCT r.rel_child_id FROM exp_relationships r, exp_weblog_titles t  WHERE r.rel_parent_id  IN( SELECT entry_id  FROM exp_weblog_titles  WHERE weblog_id = 2 )  AND r.rel_child_id = t.entry_id  AND t.weblog_id = 1" 
    backspace="1"}{rel_child_id}|{/exp:query}"}
```

Then, in **embeds/reviews**:

```
{exp:weblog:entries weblog="editions" entry_id="{embed:entry_ids}" orderby="edition-date" sort="desc" disable="categories|member_data|trackbacks" limit="10" paginate="bottom"}
    {reverse_related_entries weblog="book-reviews"}
    ...
```

Comment: fantastic. i'll give this a try tonight and let you know :)

Comment: perfect - did the job first time. Thanks!!